# Runtime.getRuntime().exec() results in java.io.IOException: Cannot run program ... no such file or directory

Tags: java, spring, process, openssl, runtime

Hi I'm generating Certificates and keys using `openssl` in Java and Spring framework,

Following is my code

```
String[] cmds = new String[4];
cmds[0] = String.format("openssl genrsa -out %s.key 2048", path+name);
cmds[1] = String.format("openssl req -new -key %s.key -out %s.csr", path+name, path+name);
cmds[2] = String.format("openssl x509 -req -in %s.csr -CA %s.pem -CAkey %s.key -CAcreateserial -out %s.crt -days 365 -sha512 -extensions mysection -extfile conf.cnf", path+name, path+rootName, path+rootName, path+name);
cmds[3] = String.format("openssl pkcs12 -export -out %s.pfx -inkey %s.key -in %s.crt", path+name, path+name, path+name);

Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = null;
try {

    p = r.exec(cmds);

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

in return I got following outut

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "openssl genrsa -out
>   /home/lalani/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/api-server/WEB-INF/applications/certificate/Riksof.key
>   2048": error=2, No such file or directory

Please guide me where I'm doing wrong?

Please also suggest me how to run this `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` in async task?

Comment: the error is simple, the key is not found. Why not try a simple location for key. Are you on linux, then simply /home/username/Riksof.key. What do you mean by run this in async task. The way you are running it is already async, as when the linux command is executed, you won't know when it's finished unless you call waitFor() method.

Comment: what is `path` and `name` here? Are you passing the correct location?

Comment: Yes from the above error `/home/lalani/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/api-server/WEB-INF/applications/certificate/` is the path and `Riksof` is name

Comment: also this is not an issue because technically this file doesn't exists this command `openssl genrsa -out Riksof.key 2048` is meant to generate a key file with the name `Riksof.key` at current location

Comment: Also I can access this dir `/home/lalani/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpw‌​ebapps/api-server/WEB-INF/applications/certificate/` using cd so the directory exists for sure

Answer (score 3):

[`Runtime.exec`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-) does not take an array of commands to run. It takes an array that describes a *single* command.

What this means is system-dependent, but generally the first element in the array is going to be the command to run, and the subsequent elements describe its arguments. For instance, if you wanted to copy `foo.txt` to `bar.txt`, you would have:

```
String[] cmd = { "cp", "foo.txt", "bar.txt" };
p = r.exec(cmd);
```

So what your code is trying to do is to invoke a program named `openssl genrsa -out /home/lalani/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/api-server/WEB-INF/applications/certificate/Riksof.key 2048`. It's trying to pass three arguments to this program, corresponding to the three last elements of your array. But that program doesn't exist — it would be a very odd program if it did!

To execute the first command in your array, you'll want an array like:

```
String[] cmd1 = { "openssl", "genrsa", "-out", path + name + ".key", "2048" };
p = r.exec(cmd1);
```

You'll need to do that for the other three commands too, of course.

The reason that text works in your terminal is that the shell actually takes the line, parses it out to its components (basically by splitting on spaces, factoring in quoted text), treats the first token (`openssl`) as the program, and the rest of the tokens as its arguments. But that functionality is part of the shell, not the underlying OS; `Runtime.exec` talks to the OS, so you need to do that splitting yourself.

Comment: No, you need to give it in an array, with each token (the program name and each arg) as a separate element. I updated my answer to show how that would look for the first command.

Comment: in actual, initially my issue that leads me to breaking all the commands into array was the first command to generate the keys works but the second command to use this key and generate certificate never works, since this func is async and dont wait for complete it exec the second command and in that case it doesn't find the key file to generate certificate

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you just need to wait for the first command to finish before you run the second. The Process object you get back has a method [to do just that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--).

Comment: The issue with `waitFor();` is its hangs after first command with no output no error, It creates key in first command and hangup in limbo

Comment: I have asked new question with the initial problem please have a look at it as well, http://stackoverflow.com/q/37113161/2552551

Answer (score 2):

Java is unable to find the program `openssl`.  You must provide the complete path to the `openssl` executable or ensure that the path to `openssl` is in the path available to the Java program.

Comment: I'm running on linux ubuntu, how do I give the path to openssl?

Comment: Do `which openssl` and use the complete path in your Java code.  Or ensure that the path shown by `which openssl` is in the path when you run your Java program.

Comment: Actually, @yshavit's answer also applies... I missed that you were trying to pass all the commands at once.  You have at least two problems.

Comment: I don't think there's any evidence that Java can't find `openssl`. It could be that it'll be able to, once the OP fixes the code to actually invoke it; on Unix-type systems (Linux, Mac) for instance, it'll work as long as openssl is on the PATH.

Comment: Yes, the simple command `r.exec(String.format("openssl genrsa -out %s.key 2048", path+name));` actually generates the keys, so that is not the case

Answer (score 0):

The question titled with "Unable to execute Runtime.getRuntime()", but the problem here is not Unable to execute Runtime.getRuntime(), but that when executing `p = r.exec(cmds);`, an IO Exception is thrown due to

```
Cannot run program "openssl genrsa -out /home/lalani/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/api-server/WEB-INF/applications/certificate/Riksof.key 2048": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: I changed the title to something more appropriate

Comment: Yes true the first half of your answer is correct, but the second  is wrong, the title should be change but The part `which means the file cannot be found in that location` is not the case here, the command `r.exec` is somehow looking for a file and not a command this is an issue here

Answer (score 0):

just fullpath the cmd you will run:
ex: "node -e index.js" ==> "/path/to/node -e /path/to/index.js"
it fixs for me, 
in my case, node is in PATH,but i don't know why it doesn't work